# Discuss Area 51: Is asking for help with a site (proposal) definition OK?

Tags: support, area-51, faq-update-request

I've asked this "[question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/please-help-with-agile-software-development-definition)" on [Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), asking for others to help define/vote for the 4 on-topic questions and 5 off-topic questions. The [FAQ](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) doesn't touch the issue whether these kind of "questions" is OK on Area 51 Discussion Zone.

From a "discussion" point I think it's OK, but you can't really think of it as a question though! Is it OK, should it just be edited into a more "question-like" format, or shouldn't we have such posts on Area 51 Discussion Zone at all?

**I think we should update the Area 51 discussions FAQ with whatever answer we agree on here.**

PS: Please, reply here to actually know your point of view rather than downvoting/upvoting the discussion, I'll delete/update it according to whatever we agree on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Area 51 Discussions are for asking questions *about* the proposals. It's not really a place to evangelize or rally that type of support. It would be like coming here to meta SO and telling everyone they need to vote on a particular post — ***"Hey everyone, please vote for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91077/discuss-area51-is-asking-for-help-with-site-proposal-definition-ok/91118#91118). It's a good one!"***

That "question" would be closed immediately.

I can understand the desire to rally and organize support for your proposal. But I'm also sure *EVERYONE* would like to see more voting and support for their proposal. Allowing those announcement-style posts would get spammy pretty fast.

Area 51 has all the features needed for people to vote on the best example questions. At some point, you have to go *outside* Area 51 to find more support. And at some point, the merits of the proposal have to stand on their own.

Comment: Actually, I'm not looking for more supporters, I'm more of looking for a way to ask the proposal followers to take note of the proposal progress (coz I think people usually forget about Area51 for a while , I know I sometimes do) .. Anyway, I get your point.. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I think we need to fix the FAQ of Area 51 to be more explicit about discouraging similar discussions though :)